# ISAPI Rewrite Rule For Multiple Query String Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

I'm trying to rewrite a URL with 2 query string parameters using HeliconTech ISAPI_Rewrite Version 3.  I'm able to rewrite the URL with 1 parameter but I can't figure out the rule(s) for rewriting 2.

Original URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?id=1234&name=John-Edward-Smith
```

Desired rewritten URL

```
http://example.com/id/1234/name/John-Edward-Smith
```

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^id/(.+)$  index.php?id=$1   [L, NC]
```

My current .htaccess file successfully rewrites the first parameter (id).  My question is how do I modify the rule or add an extra rule to also rewrite the 2nd parameter (name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^id/(\d+)/name/([^./]+)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^id/(\d+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
# Rewrite with the name
RewriteRule ^id/(\d+)/name/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]

# Rewrite with only the ID
RewriteRule ^id/(\d+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```